# How to use button styling-selectors in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, nativescript

I have a NativeScript application running and now I want to change the background color of my button when it is pressed (so that the user can see, that he really pressed it). After some googling I found that [documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/styling#using-state-selector). So I tried to apply these to my code (sadly I am not initializing my button via TS, so I cannot use the `btn = new buttonModule.Button();` line.

My html:

```
<Button [text]="'SIGNIN'|translate" (onTap)="passCredentials()"></Button>
```

My css:

```
Button {
    background-color: rgba(255, 230, 0, 1);
    font-weight: bold; 
    margin-left: 10;
    margin-right: 10;
    padding: 10;
    height: 50;
    margin-top: 30;
    margin-bottom: 25;
}
Button:pressed {
    background-color: red;
}
```

That's what I tried, but he is neither throwing an error nor changing the background-color. Do I need to tell him manually to switch between these classes? How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `highlighted` pseudo selector:

```
Button:highlighted{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: The highlighted "worked" so far, that it changes the color once it is pressed for a little while. If it is tapped over a very short period of time it is not changing. Still for some ppl. this might be a legit workaround, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

No need to write css by yourself you can use `NativeScript core theme`.
Add one of the core theme to your `app.css` file and then you can use `btn` and `btn-primary` class to your `Button` component.
Here I am sharing link for reference to import core theme to your `app.css`

[Color Schemes](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/theme#color-schemes)